# Is number of tokens the same in 3 player game and 4 player game?

Tags: quacks

The rules say that the number of tokens is limited to what's available, and yet there is no explanation how many tokens to use with 2, 3 and 4 players. I'm guessing all tokens are used in each case. What is the point of that rule, that the number of tokens is limited then, if it does not scale with the number of players?

Comment: See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames/comments/dvfwdu/quacks_of_quedlinburg_limited_tokens_is_that/

Comment: If that is important you should edit that into your question including quotes that explain what you are talking about. Comments are designed to be temporary and can go away at any time.

Comment: From a quick glance that seems to be talking about extra tokens from the expansion which add a 5th player which would not be accounted for in the base rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that there is a limited amount and you can't buy as many as you want. The rule is to remind you that you should not be adding more chips to allow for more purchases if they run out. What this means is that you will have a chance to get more of them in a two player game then you would a four player game.